# Client found response content type of 'application/wsdl+xml', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: c#, api, soap, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

```
b2bHotelSOAPService objsoap = new b2bHotelSOAPService();
        objsoap.Timeout = 20000;
        objsoap.Url = "http://api.hotelspro.com/4.1_test/hotel/b2bHotelSOAP.wsdl";
        string apiKey = Connection.AppSettings("APIKey");
        string destinationId = "LD6J";
        DateTime checkIn = new DateTime(2012, 7, 20);
        DateTime checkOut = new DateTime(2012, 7, 22);
        string strCurrencyCode = "EUR";



        pax[][]rooms=new pax[3][];
        rooms[0] = new pax[3];
        rooms[0][0] = new pax();
        rooms[0][1] = new pax();
        rooms[0][2] = new pax();


        rooms[0][0].paxType = "Adult";
        rooms[0][1].paxType="Adult";
        rooms[0][2].paxType="Child";
        rooms[0][2].age = "6";


        filter[] f = new filter[1];
        f[0] = new filter();
        f[0].filterType = "hotelStar";
        f[0].filterValue = "3";




        getAvailableHotelResponse getres = new getAvailableHotelResponse();

        getres = objsoap.getAvailableHotel(apiKey, destinationId, checkIn, checkOut, strCurrencyCode, "UK", true, rooms, f);
```

this code throwing following  error  :

```
Client found response content type of 'application/wsdl+xml', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
```

Comment: What is `objsoap`?  and why do you create `getres = new getAvailableHotelResponse();`? since you don't use it

Comment: @L.B i have made edit . I am using an api of HotelsPro.com for hotel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the WSDL in a text editor, you will find the address of the web service that you want to call

```
<soap:address location="http://api.hotelspro.com/4.1_test/hotel/b2bHotelSOAP.php"/>
```

So you'll want to change the URL that you're calling.

```
objsoap.Url = "http://api.hotelspro.com/4.1_test/hotel/b2bHotelSOAP.php";
```

The .WSDL address that you were calling is what lets .NET figure out the classes to generate, but the actual call is to the web service which is the .PHP address above.

Comment: its working now but the problem when i use json then its shows me correct number of hotels list but in case of soap it not return anything

Comment: Start a new question for that - your next problem appears to be about the actual call to the web service rather than the topic of this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495650/from-json-get-response-but-soap-zero-records