# from json get response but soap zero records

Tags: json, api, soap

I am using an api for getting the data but when i use the json i get the data with the following code

```
string apiKey = Connection.AppSettings("APIKey");
        string fullURL = "http://api.hotelspro.com/4.1_test/hotel/b2bHotelJSON.php?method=getAvailableHotel&apiKey=" + apiKey + "&destinationId=LD6J&checkIn=2012-07-20&checkOut=2012-07-24&currency=EUR&clientNationality=UK&onRequest=false&rooms[0][0][paxType]=Adult&rooms[0][1][paxType]=Adult&rooms[0][2][paxType]=Child&rooms[0][2][age]=6&rooms[1][0][paxType]=Adult&rooms[1][1][paxType]=Adult&rooms[1][2][paxType]=Child&rooms[1][2][age]=8&filters[0][filterType]=hotelStar&filters[0][filterValue]=3&filters[1][filterType]=resultLimit&filters[1][filterValue]=10";

        string text;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fullURL) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "Get";
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    throw new Exception(String.Format(
                    "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                    response.StatusCode,
                    response.StatusDescription));
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                 Response.Write(text);



            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

But when i am using the same thing below this code with soap then its showing zero records.

here is the code for soap wsdl .

```
b2bHotelSOAPService objsoap = new b2bHotelSOAPService();
        objsoap.Timeout = 20000;
        objsoap.Url = "http://api.hotelspro.com/4.1_test/hotel/b2bHotelSOAP.php";

        string destinationId = "CIEC";
        DateTime checkIn = new DateTime(2012, 7, 20);
        DateTime checkOut = new DateTime(2012, 7, 24);
        string strCurrencyCode = "EUR";



        pax[][] rooms = new pax[3][];
        rooms[0] = new pax[3];
        rooms[0][0] = new pax();
        rooms[0][1] = new pax();
        rooms[0][2] = new pax();

        rooms[1] = new pax[3];
        rooms[1][0] = new pax();
        rooms[1][1] = new pax();
        rooms[1][2] = new pax();


        rooms[0][0].paxType = "Adult";
        rooms[0][1].paxType = "Adult";
        rooms[0][2].paxType = "Child";
        rooms[0][2].age = "6";

        rooms[1][0].paxType = "Adult";
        rooms[1][1].paxType = "Adult";
        rooms[1][2].paxType = "Child";
        rooms[1][2].age = "8";



        filter[] f = new filter[2];
        f[0] = new filter();
        f[0].filterType = "hotelStar";
        f[0].filterValue = "3";

        f[1] = new filter();
        f[1].filterType = "resultLimit";
        f[1].filterValue = "20";






        getAvailableHotelResponse getres = new getAvailableHotelResponse();

        getres = objsoap.getAvailableHotel(apiKey, destinationId, checkIn, checkOut, strCurrencyCode, "UK", false, rooms, f);
```

here gets show zero records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to hotelsPro.com support team . Finally i got answer from them that i am making three rooms in this soap request but sending data only for two .

so i need to change this line

```
pax[][] rooms = new pax[3][];
```

into

```
pax[][] rooms = new pax[2][];
```

and now i am getting response from soap also. once again to thanks hotelsPro.com support team.