# C#: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface

Tags: c#, web-services

i'm using a web service from HotelsPro and trying to create an instance but it gives me an error:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface
>   'HotelsPro.hotelsProSvc.b2bHotelSOAPPortType'

here is what i'm trying to do.

**FORM1.CS**

`hotelsProSvc.b2bHotelSOAPPortType a = new b2bHotelSOAPPortType();
        getAvailableHotelResponse getres = new getAvailableHotelResponse();
          getres=a.getAvailableHotel(apiKey, "A990", checkIn, checkOut, "EUR", "UK", false, rooms, f);`

Comment: `Abstract classes have the following features:
An abstract class cannot be instantiated.` - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx)

Comment: I'll suggest you to learn more about [abstract classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx) and [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

Comment: MSDN has all this in it, even in your own language (because English is not your first language). Please start by reading the documentation for the language you are coding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# it is not possible to create an instance of an abstract class or interface.
b2bHotelSOAPPortType is either an interface or an abstract class.  If you intend on creating a new object in this way (rather than using dependency injection for instance) then you must find a concrete class that implements b2bHotelSOAPPortType and `new` that.

For example

```
hotelsProSvc.b2bHotelSOAPPortType a = new Concreteb2bHotelSOAPPortType();
```

assuming Concreteb2bHotelSOAPPortType implements b2bHotelSOAPPortType.

A better approach would be to set up the relationship between these two classes in a DI container like Autofaq.

If b2bHotelSOAPPortType  is an interface then it would be implemented thus

```
interface b2bHotelSOAPPortType {

}
```

if it is an abstract class then thus

```
abstract class b2bHotelSOAPPortType  {

}
```

What you need is to find a class that either implements b2bHotelSOAPPortType  directly or indirectly.  If it implements it directly it will look like this

```
class Concreteb2bHotelSOAPPortType : b2bHotelSOAPPortType {

}
```

If you are using Visual Studio you will be able to find which classes implement this interface or abstract class pretty easily.

Comment: i edited my question. as you can see, i need to get a response from client. because of my bad english, i couldn't understand you clearly. could you give me a small example?

Comment: Well, if this api has documentation you can find out what the implementing class(es) are and use the appropriate one.

Comment: here is another question about hotelspro service.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495650/from-json-get-response-but-soap-zero-records 
he could create an instance but i dont know how.

Answer (score 3):

Abstract classes or interfaces cannot be instanciated.

You'll have to instanciate a class that inherits from this class (or implements that interface).

Comment: i edited my question. could you give me a small example about your solution?

Comment: I've nothing really helpful to add to what @SachinKainth already said.